# Build Curl on vc9/vc11 with release dynamic library with dynamic ssl, ssh2 and dynamic zlib

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, curl, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I am trying to build curl dll library with both zlib, ssh2 and openssl support

However when I specify `release-dll-ssl-dll-ssh2-dll-zlib-dll`

I get this list:

```
Usage: nmake /f makefile.vc9 CFG=<config> <target>
where <config> is one of:
release                      - release static library
release-ssl                  - release static library with ssl
release-zlib                 - release static library with zlib
release-ssl-zlib             - release static library with ssl and zlib
release-ssl-ssh2-zlib        - release static library with ssl, ssh2 and zlib
release-ssl-dll              - release static library with dynamic ssl
release-zlib-dll             - release static library with dynamic zlib
release-ssl-dll-zlib-dll     - release static library with dynamic ssl and dynamic zlib
release-dll                  - release dynamic library
release-dll-ssl-dll          - release dynamic library with dynamic ssl
release-dll-zlib-dll         - release dynamic library with dynamic zlib
release-dll-ssl-dll-zlib-dll - release dynamic library with dynamic ssl and dynamic zlib
debug                        - debug static library
debug-ssl                    - debug static library with ssl
debug-zlib                   - debug static library with zlib
debug-ssl-zlib               - debug static library with ssl and zlib
debug-ssl-ssh2-zlib          - debug static library with ssl, ssh2 and zlib
debug-ssl-dll                - debug static library with dynamic ssl
debug-zlib-dll               - debug static library with dynamic zlib
debug-ssl-dll-zlib-dll       - debug static library with dynamic ssl and dynamic zlib
debug-dll                    - debug dynamic library
debug-dll-ssl-dll            - debug dynamic library with dynamic ssl
debug-dll-zlib-dll           - debug dynamic library with dynamic zlib1
debug-dll-ssl-dll-zlib-dll   - debug dynamic library with dynamic ssl and dynamic zlib
<target> can be left blank in which case all is assumed
Makefile.vc9(476) : fatal error U1050: please choose a valid configuration "release-dll-ssl-dll-zlib-dll-ssh2-dll"
```

Building with `release-ssl-dll-zlib-dll` works fine, but I also need sftp.

Why does this option not exist?
Is there a way around this?

Comment: can you post the command you are entering?

Comment: `nmake -f Makefile.vc9 ZLIB_PATH=..\\..\\apollo-zlib-%%ZLIB%% OPENSSL_PATH=..\\..\\apollo-openssl-%%OPENSSL_VERSION%% LIBSSH2_PATH=..\\..\\libssh2-%%LIBSSH2_VERSION%% CFG=release-ssl-ssh2-zlib`
This is how the final line looks. The paths are to where the libs are located. it compiles fine static.

Comment: Could you find a way around this?

Comment: @MukulGupta I used `CFG=release-ssl-ssh2-zlib` and you need to add the dlls required in the `link.exe` line in Makefile.vc9

Comment: @GuySoft Not sure if I understand you completely. Can you upload upload your Makefile.vc9 somewhere or explain me a little more about the change required. Did you make the change to `LNKDLL       = link.exe /DLL`? If yes, can you tell me the exact command?

Comment: @MukulGupta [Here is a patch for VC10/VC11](https://gist.github.com/guysoft/308cc529ada68f753e3b), same idea

Comment: @MukulGupta Your welcome, please update if this works for you. We could add it to [PHP winlibs](https://github.com/winlibs/cURL)

Comment: @MukulGupta Just wrote the full answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: you can't

1. What you should do is build curl with ssl, ssh2 and zlib internally using `CFG=release-ssl-ssh2-zlib`.
2. Then use [this patch](https://gist.github.com/guysoft/308cc529ada68f753e3b) to add the dlls to the link command. Note this patch is for VC10, but can easily be done on the vc9 makefile.
3. After the builds, you will need to add libssh2.lib in to lincurl.lib, if you want to build something against it (say PHP). That can be done with this command (set the paths to the your libssh2.lib and libcurl.lib):

   ```
   lib.exe /OUT:libcurl_merged.lib libssh2.lib libcurl.lib
   copy libcurl_merged.lib libcurl.lib
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use non standard build script "Makefile.vc" form "winbuild" folder.

Example for x64 dynamics lib:

```
cd curl-src\winbuild
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=14 MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=no GEN_PDB=yes  WITH_SSL=dll WITH_ZLIB=dll WITH_SSH2=dll
```

The builds will be in the top curl-src directory, builds\ directory, in 
a directory named using the options given to the nmake call.